# Is it possible to have Visual Studio Code custom configured from a .ps1 file?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to put together a standard VS Code build for my company.  I have a ps1 file that copies/installs extensions for VS Code after it's been installed but I can't seem to find how or even if it is possible to then configure VS Code settings to utilize those extensions.

For example, one of the extensions is "vscode-icons".  I can install the extension just fine but then the user needs to setup his preferences manually to actually use the extension by going to the File->Preferences->File Icon Theme->VS Code Icons.

Is it possible to have my ps1 install file actually make configuration changes so any user who opens VS Code has the custom configuration settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config settings for VS Code are JSON files - just needs to locate and edit them. 
First check what manual change is doing then create part in the script to edit the settings.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace

Comment: Perfect!!!  Thank you very much.  I'm just going to generate my own settings.json file to copy after I copy all the new extensions.  You Rock Autosvet!!!